# Can I call a tcl proc from ruby?

Tags: ruby, tcl

I want to call an existing tcl proc from ruby either directly or using a bash command and return the results to a ruby variable. Is there a way to reliably do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
tcl_file = "./file.tcl"
tcl_code = "source #{tcl_file}; name_of_proc_to_call"
result = IO.popen("tclsh", "r+") {|p| 
  p.puts tcl_code
  p.close_write
  p.read
}
```

Comment: I'd use a simple runner script and pass the real file and procedure name as arguments, since that will work even with the weirdest of file and proc names. Assuming that Ruby doesn't force problems with shell argument quoting…